# relative path is not working in sass file

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I am new to react.I have added a sass file and added a relative url.After running it give me following error.

> Error: Cannot find module
>   "../assets/images/2012_06_14_EatingRightforBloodDonation_0.jpg"

File structure is as follows:

```
-----Login
   |--assets
      |--images
           |---2012_06_14_EatingRightforBloodDonation_0.jpg   
   |--login.scss



.bg {
/* The image used */
background-image: url("../assets/images/2012_06_14_EatingRightforBloodDonation_0.jpg" );

/* Full height */
height: 100%; 

/* Center and scale the image nicely */
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

and my  webpack config is

```
    const extractStyles = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'styles/[name].[contenthash].css',
  allChunks: true,
  disable: __DEV__,
})

config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
  loader: extractStyles.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          minimize: {
            autoprefixer: {
              add: true,
              remove: true,
              browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            },
            discardComments: {
              removeAll : true,
            },
            discardUnused: false,
            mergeIdents: false,
            reduceIdents: false,
            safe: true,
            sourcemap: project.sourcemaps,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: project.sourcemaps,
          includePaths: [
            inProjectSrc('styles'),
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        loader:'resolve-url-loader'
      }
    ],
  })
})
config.plugins.push(extractStyles)

// Images
// ------------------------------------
config.module.rules.push({
  test    : /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader  : 'url-loader',
  options : {
    limit : 8192,
  },
})
```